# Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'

Tags: javascript, html

my Html >

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menuMain" class="active tabButton"  data-tabID="tabMain">M</a>
```

my javascript >

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menuMain").click(function(){
    alert($("#menuMain").getAttribute("data-tabID"));
});
```

});

it throws an error: "Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'",

any help or guidance towards a solution is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menuMain").click(function () {
        alert($("#menuMain").attr("data-tabID"));
    });
});
```

Comment: `getAttribute()` is a javascript function while `.attr()` is the jquery equivalent

Answer (score 2):

`$("#menuMain")` returns a jQuery object. jQuery objects don't have the same member functions as regular DOM objects. You have to use the functions supplied through its namespace. In particular, the equivalent function for retrieving the value of a data attribute is `data()`:

```
alert($("#menuMain").data("tabID"));
//                   ^^^^
```

As a matter of fact, since you are inside the callback of a `click()` function triggered on a jQuery object, the value of `this` is the element it references. Because of this, you don't have to repeatably specify the id of the element. You can use `$(this)` instead:

```
 alert($(this).data("tabID"));
 //    ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, and also it need to be in lower case, so it is alert($(this).data("tabid"));

Comment: @DavidPires Why does it need to be in lowercase? In your example the `ID` in `tableID` is uppercase...

Comment: "All data-* names are stored in camelCase in the jQuery data object, using W3C rules.", so 'tabID' in camelcase 'tabid' if i got tab-ID in camelCase tabId.